# "Щипит", "щипет", "щиплет" или "щипает"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, глаголы

Почему мыло **щипет** глаза?  Антисептик, который не **щипет**.

— **Щипит**, — оповестил тонкий голосок.
— Не щипит, а **щиплет**, — поправила она, — потерпи немножко, ладно?

*Юлия Комольцева. "Море волнуется — раз"*

---

Мороз **щипает** мои глаза,
И щеки горят, как розы.
Я всем расскажу, что моя слеза -
От мороза.

[Елена Мэй](http://samlib.ru/m/motyzhewa_e_n/95-3.shtml)

---

Я специально смотрела примеры с *одним* из значений глагола, но так и не смогла однозначно выбрать: как правильно?

Дополнение к вопросу. Словарь трудностей русского языка. Ударение. Грамматические формы. Наталия Еськова:

[**щипит**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=vFimCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA311&lpg=PA311&dq=%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82&source=bl&ots=wkSjzhEd1Y&sig=-h42AbUjiOIJhxWvhztGh5_R46Q&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMh7_rgvfSAhXCFSwKHU3fDi04bhDoAQgbMAE#v=onepage&q=%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82&f=false)

Comment: Задала вопрос по поводу словаря Еськовой - призову светил сайта: http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2459553-slovar-trudnostej-russkogo-jazyka-n-eskovoj-schipit-sypit-trepit.html

Answer (score 4):

"Щипит" - это детсадовское (и моё тоже).

"Щипает" будет истрактовано как "народно-поэтическое", ну а что с плохих стихов взять?

Зато [словарь Трудностей произношения](http://diffc_ru.academic.ru/10381/%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) и ударения в современном русском языке нам всё красиво разобъяснил: только **щиплет**, а то, что им, словарём, "не рекомендовано", равносильно: запрещено (в нормативной речи).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Другие словари дают у форм *щипет, щипает* (не *щипит, щипишь*) помету "разговорное", разрешает, значит...

Ога, нашла ещё один [категорический источник](http://common_mistakes.academic.ru/150/%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 Постскриптум.

В книге отчаянно шифрующейся Юлии Комольцевой, так себе стилисточки, либо авторское **и** в "щипит", либо корректор проспал. Это же прямая речь, звук, в нём не может быть орфографических ошибок, только грамматические.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78976/discussion-on-answer-by-galina-avanesova-----).